# Add partition in MySQL Table to an Already Partitioned Table

Tags: mysql, partitioning

I have table as below:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST_P (
    ID VARCHAR(64),
    F_NAME int NOT NULL,
    L_NAME VARCHAR(64),
    CREATETS DATETIME NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(DATA_TRACE_ID,CREATETS)
)
PARTITION BY RANGE(DAY(CREATETS))(
        PARTITION day1 VALUES LESS THAN (2),
        PARTITION day2 VALUES LESS THAN (3),
        PARTITION day3 VALUES LESS THAN (4),
        PARTITION day4 VALUES LESS THAN (5),
        PARTITION day5 VALUES LESS THAN (6),
        PARTITION day6 VALUES LESS THAN (7),
        PARTITION day7 VALUES LESS THAN (8),
        PARTITION day8 VALUES LESS THAN (9),
        PARTITION day9 VALUES LESS THAN (10),
        PARTITION day10 VALUES LESS THAN (11),
        PARTITION day11 VALUES LESS THAN (12),
        PARTITION day12 VALUES LESS THAN (13),
        PARTITION day13 VALUES LESS THAN (14),
        PARTITION day14 VALUES LESS THAN (15),
        PARTITION day15 VALUES LESS THAN (16),
        PARTITION day16 VALUES LESS THAN (17),
        PARTITION day17 VALUES LESS THAN (18),
        PARTITION day18 VALUES LESS THAN (19),
        PARTITION day19 VALUES LESS THAN (20),
        PARTITION day20 VALUES LESS THAN (21),
        PARTITION day21 VALUES LESS THAN (22),
        PARTITION day22 VALUES LESS THAN (23),
        PARTITION day23 VALUES LESS THAN (24),
        PARTITION day24 VALUES LESS THAN (25),
        PARTITION day25 VALUES LESS THAN (26),
        PARTITION day26 VALUES LESS THAN (27),
        PARTITION day27 VALUES LESS THAN (28),
        PARTITION day28 VALUES LESS THAN (29),
        PARTITION day29 VALUES LESS THAN (30),
        PARTITION day30 VALUES LESS THAN (31),
        PARTITION day31 VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE
);
```

I want to write a Script that drops the Partition for today+1 day and create a new partition for with the same partitioning condition.
for example:

I want to drop partition day5 as I want to delete the data in this table.

I am doing this:

```
ALTER TABLE TEST_P REORGANIZE PARTITION day5 into 
(PARTITION day5 VALUES LESS THAN (5),
    PARTITION day6 VALUES LESS THAN (6),
    PARTITION day7 VALUES LESS THAN (7),
    PARTITION day8 VALUES LESS THAN (8),
    PARTITION day9 VALUES LESS THAN (9),
    PARTITION day10 VALUES LESS THAN (10),
    PARTITION day11 VALUES LESS THAN (11),
    PARTITION day12 VALUES LESS THAN (12),
    PARTITION day13 VALUES LESS THAN (13),
    PARTITION day14 VALUES LESS THAN (14),
    PARTITION day15 VALUES LESS THAN (15),
    PARTITION day16 VALUES LESS THAN (16),
    PARTITION day17 VALUES LESS THAN (17),
    PARTITION day18 VALUES LESS THAN (18),
    PARTITION day19 VALUES LESS THAN (19),
    PARTITION day20 VALUES LESS THAN (20),
    PARTITION day21 VALUES LESS THAN (21),
    PARTITION day22 VALUES LESS THAN (22),
    PARTITION day23 VALUES LESS THAN (23),
    PARTITION day24 VALUES LESS THAN (24),
    PARTITION day25 VALUES LESS THAN (25),
    PARTITION day26 VALUES LESS THAN (26),
    PARTITION day27 VALUES LESS THAN (27),
    PARTITION day28 VALUES LESS THAN (28),
    PARTITION day29 VALUES LESS THAN (29),
    PARTITION day30 VALUES LESS THAN (30),
    PARTITION day31 VALUES LESS THAN (31),
    PARTITION p_default VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE)
```

But I get

> Error in list of partitions to REORGANIZE

This table grows very large very fast, so I want to delete a month old data in this and not affect the performance of the table.

Comment: Is this the same same as [exchange partition](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/partitioning-management-exchange.html) with an empty table and then dropping the extracted table?

Comment: `REORGANIZE PARTITION` is used to split up a partition into new partitions, they can't overlap other partitions.

Comment: `REORGANIZE` can combine or split.  The problem is with day6, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A sliding time series is one of the few use cases for `PARTITIONing`.  Unfortunately, your approach is inefficient (if it can even be fixed).

Instead, have actual days (not day of month) and add one new partition each night -- by `REORGANIZEing` the 'future' partition into tomorrow's day and a new 'future'.  Also, `DROP PARTITION` to toss the oldest.  Detail [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint).